# Age differences between Lord Rama & Lakshman, Balram & Lord Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ramayana, rama

What were the Age differences between Lord Rama & Lakshman according to Valmiki-Ramayana, Balram & Lord Krishna according to Vyas-Mahabharata?

I mean age difference between Elder brother Lord Rama & Lakshman.

I mean age difference between Elder brother Balram & Lord Krishna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to remember that Sri Rama and Lakshmana are sons of same king Dasaratha but born to 2 different mothers, ie., Kausalya and Sumitra.

Whereas, Balarama and Sri Krishna are brothers of same parents, Vasudeva and Devaki.  However, during the pregnancy, [the embryo of Balarama had been transferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balarama#Legends) from the womb of
Devaki to that of Rohini, the eldest wife of Vasudeva.

---

Sri Rama was born on Punarvasu nakshtra, Bharata on Pushymi, while Lakshmana and Satrugna were born in Āshleshā Nakshatra.

According to Ramayana, [Sri Rama was born](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga18/bala_18_frame.htm) on the Ninth day of Chaitra month, whereas Lakshmana was born on later part of 10th day of Chaitra month.

So age difference between Sri Rama and Lakshmana is maximum of 2 days only.

---

In respect of Balarama , the embryo was transferred from Devaki to Rohini.  After that Devaki conceived again and gave birth to Sri Krishna.

Hence, at least 1 year gap will be there between the birth of Balarama and Sri Krishna.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

Valmiki seems to anticipate the potential misunderstanding regarding Lakshmana and Shatrughna’s births. In 1.18.16, he uses the term “sajjñire pṛthak” (born separately) right after mentioning their shared nakshatra, emphasizing that all four brothers were born individually. “rājñaḥ putrā mahātmānaścatur vargaḥ sajjñire pṛthak| guṇavanto’nurūpāśca rucyā proṣṭhapadopamāḥ||” (1–18–16) which means, “Thus there are four great-souled sons of Dasharatha, born separately, endowed with virtues according to their nature and by their brilliance”.

Please check [this blog post of mine](https://medium.com/@vbalebai/decoding-the-birth-order-of-lord-rama-lakshmana-bharatha-and-shatrughna-a-closer-look-at-valmiki-a13fb83e2dc3) for more details.